# discord.js finding when user was created

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on discord bot that tells you information about a user.
I did everything else. But I can't get the time when the user has created their account.
(Sorry for my bad english.)
I tried doing this :

```
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    const member = message.guild.member(user);
    message.channel.send(member.author.createdAt());
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for when the user was created, you can simply just use the following:

```js
const user = message.mentions.users.first();
message.channel.send(user.createdAt.toString());
```

If you're looking for when they joined the server, then you can use the following:

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
message.channel.send(member.joinedAt.toString());
```